# run-time error '438' for outlook items on VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

How can I solve the
run-time error '438':
Object doesn't support this property or method
error, occurs on the "If olMail.SenderEmailAddress = "deneme@deneme.com" Then" line, for the vba code below

```
Sub MaildenDosyaKopyala()
    Dim olApp As Object
    Dim olNamespace As Object
    Dim olFolder As Object
    Dim olMail As Object
    Dim olAttachment As Object
    Dim DesktopPath As String
    Dim FilePath As String
    Dim FileName As String
    
    ' Outlook uygulamasını başlat
    Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set olNamespace = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    
    ' Gelen Kutusu'nu aç
    Set olFolder = olNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' 6, gelen kutusunu temsil eder. Diğer klasörler için numaraları değiştirin.
    
    ' Masaüstü yolunu al
    DesktopPath = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop")
    FileName = "aaa.xlsx"
    
    ' Gelen mailleri kontrol et
    For Each olMail In olFolder.Items
        If olMail.SenderEmailAddress = "deneme@deneme.com" Then
            For Each olAttachment In olMail.Attachments
                If olAttachment.FileName = FileName Then
                    FilePath = DesktopPath & "\" & FileName
                    olAttachment.SaveAsFile FilePath
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next olAttachment
        End If
    Next olMail
    
    Set olAttachment = Nothing
    Set olMail = Nothing
    Set olFolder = Nothing
    Set olNamespace = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

could not find any solution

Comment: Do you have subfolders in Inbox?

Answer (score 0):

Your inbox can contain items other than `MailItem`, such as `ReportItem` or `MeetingRequestItem` which do not expose the `SenderEmailAddress`  property.

Check first that you have a mail item:

```vb
If olMail.Class = 43 Then '43 is olMailItem
```

Or, better yet, don't loop through all items in a folder (which can contain thousands of items), let the message store do the heavy lifting:

```vb
For Each olMail In olFolder.Items.Restrict("[SenderEmailAddress] = 'deneme@deneme.com' ")
```